# Finding the $N$-th derivative of $f(x)=\frac {x} {x^2-1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm practicing some problems from past exams and found this one:

> Find the n-th derivative of this function:
> $$f(x)=\frac {x} {x^2-1}$$

---

I have no idea how to start solving this problems. Is there any theorem for finding nth derivative?

Comment: Do you need the *exact* derivative, or just its shape?

Comment: @Marco Castronovo  It doesn't say. :(

Comment: More generally, the partial fraction decomposition of a complex rational fraction $f(X)$ can be computed as follows. The singular part of $f(X)$ at an order $m$ pole $a$ is obtained by dividing by $(X-a)^m$ the degree $<m$ Taylor approximation of $(X-a)^m f(X)$ at $a$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe we can add some more help -just in case you didn't succeed to find the answer yourself yet. Let

$$
\frac{x}{x^2 - 1} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+1}
$$

be the splitting into partial fractions. (I'm too lazy to compute the coeffitients $A$ and $B$.) Then

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{x^2 - 1} = -\frac{A}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{B}{(x+1)^2}  \ .
$$

Differentiating again,

$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{x}{x^2 - 1}  = \frac{2A}{(x-1)^3} + \frac{2B}{(x+1)^3} \ .
$$

One more time:

$$
\frac{d^3}{dx^3} \frac{x}{x^2 - 1} = - \frac{3\cdot 2 A}{(x-1)^4} - \frac{3\cdot 2 B}{(x+1)^4} \ .
$$

And sure enough you can find the general pattern now, can't you? Then, use induction to prove your guess.

Comment: As usual, lots and lots of great answers, so big thank you to everyone! I selected this one because it helped me the most.

Answer (score 14):

**HINT** $\;\;\;$ Upon employing partial fractions it reduces to $\;\;\;\rm D^n \:\frac{1}{x+1}. \;\;$ Now employ the Taylor series

$$\rm\;  f(t+x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \;\; D^n \: f(x) \; \frac{t^n}{n!}$$

and note that for this problem  we've  $\rm\; f(t+x) = \frac{1}{t+x+1}$ is a geometric series with known coefficients.

Such "generating function" approaches often work smoothly even in much more complicated problems. Indeed, there is a very powerful **Umbral calculus** that frequently succeeds in computing such closed form expressions, e.g. see Steven Roman: The Umbral Calculus. 1984. For example, below is a small sample of derivative formulas for the countless number of polynomial sequences amenable to umbral calculus analysis

$$\begin{array}{|r|l|} 
\hline
\rm Name & \rm Derivative \; formula \\
\hline\hline
\rm Laguerre  & \rm L_n^k(x) = (D+1)^{n+k}(-x)^n \\
\rm Exponential & \rm\;\; e_n(x) = e^{-x}(xD)^n e^x  \\
\rm Abel & \rm A_n^k(x) = x \; e^{-knD} x^{n-1} \\
\rm Hermite  & \rm H_n^k(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2/(2n)} (kD)^n e^{-x^2/(2n)} \\
\rm Bernoulli & \rm B_n^k(x) = \left(\frac{D}{e^D-1}\right)^k  x^n \\
\rm Euler  & \rm E_n^k(x) = \left(\frac{2}{e^D+1}\right)^k  x^n \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 12):

Split it into partial fractions then differentiate.

Comment: When I do that, I can't find any pattern by which I guess how nth derivative will look like.

Comment: @Andrejako, see J. Mangaldan's hint below.

Answer (score 9):

To add to Derek's hint: you will have to show the validity of the formula

$\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k}\frac1{x}=\frac{(-1)^k k!}{x^{k+1}}$

Answer (score 3):

According to the Binomial Theorem (or using the usual formula for the sum of a geometric series with initial term 1 and common ratio $x^2$),

$f(x)=\frac {x} {x^2-1} = -x \frac {1} {1 - x^2} = -x \left( 1 + x^2 + x^4 + \cdots + x^{2n} + \cdots \right)$

$= -x - x^3 - x^5 - \cdots - x^{2n+1} - \cdots$.

Because the right side converges absolutely for $|x^2| < 1$ you can differentiate it term by term, introducing a coefficient $(2n+1)(2n) \cdots (2n+1-k+1)$ for $x^{2n+1-k}$; in other words, the coefficient of $x^j$ is $(j+1)(j+2) \cdots (j+k)$.  Dividing the entire thing through by $k!$ gives a series you can easily relate to the binomial expansion of $( 1 - x^2 ) $ to a *negative* integral value, yielding a closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

related problem: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2/193914#193914). I am referring you to this [book](https://www.morebooks.de/search/gb?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mhenni) where you will find the complete answer to the problem of finding the nth derivative of rational polynomials and other classes of functions.

**Added** Some people suggested the post should be self-contained. Here is the example I am referring to

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{ x^2 + x - 1 } { x^4 + x^3 - x - 1 }\,.
\end{equation}
The roots of the denominator are
\begin{equation}\nonumber
x = -1, 1, -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{ i \sqrt{3}}{2}, -\frac{1}{2} -
\frac{ i \sqrt{3}}{2}\,.
\end{equation}
Expressing the function in the partial fraction form
\begin{equation}\nonumber
f(x) = \frac{ x^2 + x - 1 } { x^4 + x^3 - x - 1 } =
\frac{a_1}{x-1} + \frac{a_2}{x+1} + \frac{a_3}{ x + \frac{1 -
i\sqrt{3}}{2}} + \frac{a_4}{ x + \frac{1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}}\,.
\end{equation} 
To find $a_i$, one can use the formula

> $$ a_{ i_{\ell}} = \mathrm{Res}( ( x - \alpha_{\ell} )^{{i_\ell} - 1
> } f(x)\,, x = \alpha_\ell) \,,\quad i_\ell = 1,2,...,m_\ell, $$

where $ \alpha_{\ell} $ are the roots of the denominator and the formula takes care of the multiplicities $m_{\ell}$ of the roots in case there is any. For instance,

\begin{align}\nonumber
a_1 & = \mathrm{Res}\left( \frac{ x^2 + x - 1 } { x^4 + x^3 - x -
1 }, x = 1 \right)&
\\ \nonumber
\\ \nonumber
& = \lim_{x = 1} (x-1)\frac{ x^2 + x - 1 } { x^4 + x^3 - x - 1 }&
\\ \nonumber
\\ \nonumber
& = \frac{1}{6}\,,&
\end{align}

Once we have the function in the partial fraction form, the $nth$ derivative
can be found directly by using the formula
\begin{equation}
D^n ( x - \alpha )^{(-k)} =
{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n}\Gamma  \left( n+k \right) }{\Gamma 
\left( k \right) }}(x-\alpha)^{-k-n}.
\end{equation}

Following the above techniques, the final answer is

$$ \begin{align}\nonumber
f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^n \Gamma(n+1) \, &\left(
\frac{1}{2\,(x+1)^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{6\,(x-1)^{n+1}}  \right. &
\\ \nonumber
\\ \nonumber
& \left. + \frac{\frac{ - 1 - i\sqrt{3}}{3}}{ \left(x + \frac{1 -
i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{n+1} } + \frac{\frac{ - 1 + i\sqrt{3}}{3}}{
\left(x + \frac{1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{n+1}} \right) \,. &
\end{align}.$$