# Finding derivative of $f(x) = x^{\arctan x}$

Tags: calculus

I need help understanding how to derivate this function:

$$f(x) = x^{\arctan(x)}$$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I am studying for an exam, this was from an old one and I am trying to understand it.

Comment: Write it as g(h(x)) or maybe more steps, where each function is one you know how to differentiate.  Apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^{\arctan{x}}$ then $\log{f(x)} = \arctan{x} \cdot \log x$. Therefore $$\frac{1}{f(x)} \times f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \Bigl[ \arctan{x} \cdot \log x \Bigr] \Longrightarrow f'(x) = f(x) \times  \frac{d}{dx} \Bigl[ \arctan{x} \cdot \log x \Bigr]$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\ \  g^{\:h}\ =\ e^{h\: \log(g)}\:.\ $ Or, take logs, cf. [logarithmic derivative,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative) and my [post here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773)

Comment: is there a name for that rule? Trying to find out more about it...

Comment: exp and log are inverse functions: $\exp(\log\ g) = g$ on $\mathbb R^+$