# What is the derivative of $f(n) = n^2 - 9 \bmod 16$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, derivatives, polynomials

I'm reading Tom M. Apostol's introduction to analytic number theory.  In chapter 2 he defines

[image: derivative of arithmetical function]

Does his definition apply to this modular polynomial in the question?  I feel it does not.  I'd think the derivative of the function in the question is just $f'(n) = 2n$. That's the [formal derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative).  I'm interested in knowing what $f'(n)$ is like in his theorem 5.30.  What derivative is that?

[image: Theorem 5.30]

Comment: Since Apostol has called it a definition, it need not match what you call a formal derivative.

Comment: This is a different kind of derivative. You can’t apply the real derivative to arithmetical functions, because they are only defined on $\mathbb N^+,$ so the real definition of derivative as a limit  cannot be applied to arithmetical functions.

Comment: Please do not rely on images for text. They are not searchable (either within the site or by search engines), so future users will be unable to locate this post based on its content. They may not display properly for everyone. And screen readers cannot process them, which makes the post inaccessible to users who use screenreaders. The site has excellent mathematical typesetting capabilities, so please avail yourself of them.

Comment: If I apply his definition to the polynomial in the question, I get $f'(n) = f(n) \log(n)$, so $f'(5) = 16\log(5)$, which is not an integer.

Comment: By the way, if $g(n)=(17n^2-9)\bmod 16,$ you’d have $g’(n)=34n,$ but $g(n)=f(n),$ so your definition of derivative would be not of a function, but of its written representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arithmetic functions are only defined on $\mathbb N^+,$ so you can’t use the calculus limit definition to get a standard derivative.

So in your case, you just apply the definition:

$$f’(n)=(n^2-9\bmod 16)\log n$$

The relation to calculus definitions is if $f$ is arithmetical, then there is  a related function, $F,$ (called a [Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series)):

$$F(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)n^t$$

Usually defined for $t$ with a negative upper bound on the real part, but you can also think of $F$ as an abstract series, the way you can think of power series abstractly. (Dirichlet series are usually defined in terms of $s,$ where $t=-s,$ but I chose this version because it otherwise changes the sign of $F’.$)

Then:

$$F’(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(n)\cdot f(n)n^t=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f’(n)n^t$$

where $F’$ is the usual calculus/complex analysis derivative, and $f’$ is Apostol’s definition for arithmetical functions.

The relation between $F$ and $f$ is crucial in studying arithmetical functions. Given $f,g$ arithmetical and corresponding Dirichlet series $F,G,$ the Dirichlet series for $f+g$ is $F+G,$ and the Dirichlet series of $h=f*g,$ where:

$$(f*g)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)$$ has corresponding Dirichlet series, $H(t)=F(t)G(t).$

On thing you get from this correspondence is the usual identities:$$(\alpha f)’=\alpha\cdot (f’)\\(f+g)’=f’+g’\\(f*g)’=f’*g +f*g’.$$
where $\alpha$ is a constant.

Comment: Re: final paragraph: if $Lf := Df/f\,$ then $\,L(fg) = Lf + Lg\iff D(fg) = fDg + gDf,\,$ cf. [logarithmic differentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90588/242)

Comment: Not sure how that applies here. Is $fg$ the same as $f*g?$ Is $Df/f$ actual function division, or $*$-multiplication by the $*$-inverse of $f?$ If $f(1)=0$ there is no $*$-inverse of $f.$ The actual result follows directly from $\log(n)=\log(d)+\log(n/d)$ so this seems like overkill. 
@BillDubuque