# Theory of Partial Fraction Decomposition

Tags: partial-fractions

The function in question that I want to decompose is $$\dfrac{8x^3 + 7}{(x+1)(2x+1)^3}$$

I had the idea to to break this down into:
$$\dfrac{A}{x+1} + \dfrac{Bx^2 +Cx + D}{(2x+1)^3} + \dfrac{Ex + F}{(2x+1)^2} + \dfrac{G}{2x+1}$$

Well this turns into a really messy system of 4 equations and 7 variables.
Is there an easier way to decompose the function? Can I possibly eliminate any of these variables at the outset?

Comment: Here is a partial fraction technique which handles this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/nth-derivative-of-a-function-i-dont-know-where-to-start).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html) rule, it will be $$\frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{(2x+1)^3} + \frac{E}{(2x+1)^2} + \frac{G}{2x+1}$$

Comment: @Mark, could you have a look into the link in the answer or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction#Illustration

Answer (score 2):

I'll simply alert you to the existence of two separate methods for dealing with partial fractions with repeated roots that may potentially simplify the process:

1) [Ostrogradsky's method](http://thewaythetruthandthelife.net/index/2_background/2-1_cosmological/2-1-11_math/2-1-11-12_analysis/2-1-11-12-04_indefinite-integrals.htm#4.5.2%20Ostrogradsky%27s%20method)

2) [Hardy's Method](http://archive.org/details/integrationoffun00hardrich) (Page 10 on)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to break it down into $\displaystyle\frac{A}{x+1}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{Bx^2 + Cx + D}{(2x+1)^3}.$ What you end up with is
$\begin{align*}
8A + B &= 8\\
12A + B +C &= 0\\
6A + C + D &= 0\\
A + D &= 7
\end{align*}$

Solving gives $A = 1, B = 0, C = -12, D =6.$

Note that this is equivalent to lab bhattacharjee's decomposition.