# Find coefficient of $x^8$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)^c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find coefficient of $x^8$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)^c$

Help me please

I don't know what to do after that because of the exponent $c$

Comment: Hint: Use $$\dfrac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$$ and the binomial series to answer the question.

Comment: Hint: You should get $\binom{-c}{8}=\binom{c+7}{8}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that,

$$ 1+x+x^2 +\dots = \frac{1}{1-x} \implies  (1+x+x^2 +\dots)^c = (1-x)^{-c}. $$

Now, use the derivative techniques and evaluate it at zero and divide by $8!$. See a [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/nth-derivative-of-a-function-i-dont-know-where-to-start).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. First recognize that 
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)^c = {1\over(1-x)^c},$$
for $|x| < 1$.  Differentiate 8 times and set $x = 0$.