# Taylor series and 100th derivative on this function

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have this real function:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x^2-2x+3)^2}$ and I need to find Taylor series at $x = 1$ and find 100th derivative at $f^{(100)}(1)$.

Can anybody help me???

Comment: To obtain a numerical answer for the value of $f^{(100)} (1)$, follow this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D[1%2F%28x^%282%29+-+2+x+%2B+3%29^%282%29%2C{x%2C100}]+%2F.+x+-%3E+1)

Comment: Maybe we had some misunderstanding here. Firstly, I need to find Taylor series for this function and then find 100th derivative ... does anybody know that???

Comment: I might be missing the point, but it seems to me you will need to know complex calculus. Are you familiar with Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/nth-derivative-of-a-function-i-dont-know-where-to-start#comment670114_171020).

Answer (score 13):

Notice
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{((x-1)^2+2)^2}
= \frac14 \left(1 + \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\right)^{-2}
\stackrel{\color{blue}{[1]}}{=} \frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{2^n} (x-1)^{2n}
$$
The coefficient for $(x-1)^{100}$ in the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ around $x = 1$
is $\frac{51}{2^{52}}$ and hence

$$f^{(100)}(1) = \frac{51\times 100!}{2^{52}}$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ Please note that for general $\alpha$, we have
  $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha} = 1 + \alpha z + \frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)}{2} z^2 + \cdots + \frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (\alpha+k)}{n!} z^n + \cdots$$
  When $\alpha = 2$, this reduces to
  $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = 1 + 2 z + \frac{3!}{2!} z^2 + \cdots + \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} z^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)z^n$$
  Another way to look at this is start from the power series:
  $$\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$$
  If one differentiate both sides once, you get
  $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = 1 + 2z + 3z^2 \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)z^n$$
  Expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha}$ for other integral $\alpha > 0$ can be derived in similar manner. You can really view this sort of expansion as
  as an extension of ordinary binomial theorem to negative integral power.

Comment: this is the best explanation I used. ;)