# Find a formula for $f^{(n)}(x)$ where $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2-a^2}$

Tags: calculus

> Let $a$ be a constant. Find a formula for $f^{(n)}(x)$ where $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2-a^2}$.

After computing a few derivatives, the derivatives seem to have factorials in them sometimes and other times not. For example, $\dfrac{d^5}{dx^5} \left (\dfrac{1}{x^2-a^2} \right) = -\dfrac{240(3a^4x+10a^2x^3+3x^5)}{(x^2-a^2)^6}$ while $\dfrac{d^6}{dx^6} \left (\dfrac{1}{x^2-a^2} \right) = -\dfrac{720(a^6+21a^4x^2+35a^2x^4+7x^6)}{(x^2-a^2)^6}$, so I am not immediately seeing the pattern.

Comment: Your value for the sixth derivative can't be right, because the value at $x=0$ should not be zero (you can see that the Taylor series around zero has a non-zero coefficient there.) I thin it should be $a^6$ rather than $a^6x$.

Comment: Actually, I think both your calculations are wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right I was being careless.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/nth-derivative-of-a-function-i-dont-know-where-to-start)

Answer (score 6):

Just observe that
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{x-a}-\frac{1}{x+a}\right)$$

Then
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{2a}\left[\frac{1}{(x-a)^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{(x+a)^{n+1}}\right]$$

Comment: If should be $n+1$ in the exponent in the denominators: $\frac{1}{(x-a)^{n+1}}$.

Comment: And the coefficients of the numerator are seen to be binomial coefficients. You get $$f^{n}(x)=(-1)^nn!\frac{\sum_{k\text{ odd}}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}a^{k-1}}{(x^2-a^2)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How did you simplify it like that?

Comment: Actually, my formula was wrong. But only because I forgot my previous comment. The actual closed form for the numerator is:$$\sum_{k\text{ odd}} \binom{n+1}{k}x^{n+1-k}x^{n-k}a^{k-1}$$. This is the value of $$\frac{1}{2a}\left((x+a)^{n+1}-(x-a)^{n+1}\right)$$. The even terms cancel, so you are left with the odd terms.

Answer (score 0):

$$
{1 \over {x^{\,2}  - a^{\,2} }} = {1 \over {\left( {x + a} \right)\left( {x - a} \right)}} = {1 \over {2\,a}}\left( {{1 \over {\left( {x - a} \right)}} - {1 \over {\left( {x + a} \right)}}} \right)
$$
... then it goes easily ..