# Find a formula for $f^{(n)}(x)$ where $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^3-a^2x}$

Tags: calculus

> Let $a$ be a constant. Find a formula for $f^{(n)}(x)$ where $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^3-a^2x}$.

I think if we separated this two fractions it might help [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700939/find-a-formula-for-fnx-where-fx-dfrac1x2-a2) result. We then have $\dfrac{1}{x^3-a^2x} = \dfrac{1}{x} \cdot\dfrac{1}{x^2-a^2}$. Is there way to use the value of the second terms $n$th derivative to find the $n$th derivative of the $f(x)$ we want?

Comment: Have you tried decomposing into simple fractions?

Comment: You can do partial fraction decomposition--then the derivatives should all be "nice" (I think).  Since that can be written as $f(x) = \frac{1}{x(x - a)(x + a)}$

Comment: Ah, that does it. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/nth-derivative-of-a-function-i-dont-know-where-to-start).